# How to "merge" repeated column values in a long-format data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a Shiny app that shows a long-format data frame.

It all works fine, but I would like it to look better. Right now, it looks like a typical R long format data frame. However, I would like it to look like this (this is a random example from google):

[example of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2NiY.png)

Not the colors/font etc., just the fact that, in the first column, the name of the rows are "merged" to make it easier to read and better looking

is there an easy way to do this with Shiny and renderDataTable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to merge rows in dataTables, as stated by [this post](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/346) on GitHub. It may be possible to build a HTML widget for this, but I imagine it would be a lot of work to do so.

Comment: Thanks, Harvey. I was not able to find that post. Thanks for the info anyway :-)